# Solving two coupled ODEs by matrix form in Python

Tags: python, scipy, odeint

I want to solve a coupled system of ODEs in matrix form which has such a form:

> y'_n = ((m_n)**2) * y_n+(C * y)_n  ,   m'_n=-4*m_n*y_n

where `C` is a matrix, `[2 1, -1 3]`.

On the other hand I want to solve these equations:

> y'1= m1 ** 2 * y1 + 2 * y1 + y2
>    y'2= m2 ** 2 * y2 - y1 + 3 * y3
>    m'1= -4 * m1 * y1 ,
>   m'2= -4 * m2 * y2
>    y1(0)=y2(0)=-15. and m1(0)=m2(0)=0.01

in matrix form and I wrote the following program:

```
import numpy as np
from pylab import plot,show
from scipy.integrate import odeint

C=np.array([[2,1],[-1,3]])
dt=0.001
def dy_dt(Y,time):
 y,m=Y
 m=m+dt*(-4.*m*y)
 dy=m**2*y+np.dot(C,y)
 return dy

m_init=np.ones(2)*0.01
time=np.linspace(0,4,1/dt)
y_init=np.ones(2)*-15.
y_tot=odeint(dy_dt,[y_init,m_init],time)


plot(time,y_tot[0])#y_1
plot(time,y_tot[1])#y_2
plot(time,y_tot[2])#m_1
plot(time,y_tot[3])#m_2
show()
```

but I encountered the following error:

```
 y_tot=odeint(dy_dt,[y_init,m_init],time)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy/integrate/odepack.py", line 215, in odeint
    ixpr, mxstep, mxhnil, mxordn, mxords)
ValueError: Initial condition y0 must be one-dimensional.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The initial value to odeint must be an array, not a matrix.  Try use `y0=np.hstack((y_init, m_init))` and put that as the initial value (y0 is the second argument to odeint).

Comment: when I run it I encouter to this error:               
    y,m=Y
ValueError: too many values to unpack

Comment: This answer solves the problem posed in the question.  If you have another problem, ask another question!

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser Apparently doesn't. What's with the attitude? The answer is an untested instruction not an answer.

Comment: @percusse: Yes, it does solve the problem stated in the question.  `ValueError: too many values to unpack` is a new error that is caused by a different problem.